# error: updating values of elevator and user after clicking button

Tags: javascript

I am creating one program of the elevator which includes up, down buttons (external functions) and buttons (0 to 5:: internal functions) inside the elevator my external functions are working correctly but when inside elevator user press any button elevator should go to that place. and update the position of user and elevator. But when I press the button(0,1,2,3,4,5) it doesn't work. Can anyone help me to solve the issue. Thanks in advance.

```
code::

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>elevator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Internal Functions</h2>
  <span>current user position :: </span>
  <p id="userPosition"></p>
  <span>current elevator position :: </span>
  <p id="elevatorPostion"></p>

  <button id="btn" onclick="inFunction(0)" value="0">0</button>
  <button id="btn" onclick="inFunction(1)" value="1">1</button>
  <button id="btn" onclick="inFunction(2)" value="2">2</button>
  <button id="btn" onclick="inFunction(3)" value="3">3</button>
  <button id="btn" onclick="inFunction(4)" value="4">4</button>
  <button id="btn" onclick="inFunction(5)" value="5">5</button>

  <h2>External Functions</h2>
  user position:
  <input type="text" id="userText" name="UserPosition" value="0">

  <button onclick="exFunction('up')">UP</button>
  <button onclick="exFunction('down')">DOWN</button>
  <script>
    var userPosition = 0,
      elevatorPosition = 4

    function exFunction(pressedValue) {
      console.log(pressedValue);
      var userPosition = document.getElementById("userText").value;
      document.getElementById("userPosition").innerHTML = userPosition;
      document.getElementById("elevatorPostion").innerHTML = elevatorPosition;

      var intervalEle = setInterval(function () {

        if (userPosition > elevatorPosition) {
          console.log('Elevator position', elevatorPosition);
          elevatorPosition++;
        } else if (userPosition < elevatorPosition) {
          elevatorPosition--;
        } else {
          elevatorPosition == userPosition;
          clearInterval(intervalEle);
        }

        document.getElementById("userPosition").innerHTML = userPosition;
        document.getElementById("elevatorPostion").innerHTML = elevatorPosition;

      }, 1000);
    }

    function inFunction(clickedValue) {
      var btnValue = document.querySelector('btn').value;
      document.getElementById("userPosition").innerHTML = userPosition;
      document.getElementById("elevatorPostion").innerHTML = elevatorPosition;

      console.log(btnValue);

      var intervalEle2 = setInterval(function () {
        if (elevatorPosition > btnValue) {
          elevatorPosition--
        } else if (elevatorPosition < btnValue) {
          elevatorPosition++
        } else {
          elevatorPosition == btnValue;
          clearInterval(intervalEle2)
        }

        document.getElementById("userPosition").innerHTML = userPosition;
        document.getElementById("elevatorPostion").innerHTML = elevatorPosition;
      }, 1000)

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

output :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKeeL.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var btnValue = document.querySelector('btn').value;
```

There are no `<btn>` elements on your page, so `document.querySelector('btn')` returns `null`. You've illegally reused `"btn"` as an id, so `document.getElementById('btn')` won't do what you expect either.

You've already got the number of the button that was clicked; you passed it in to `inFunction` as `clickedValue`. Just use that.